# lower_bound acts weirdly in the function and normally in the main()

Tags: c++, lower-bound

I have this piece of code:

```
        int main() {
            const vector<string> sorted_strings = { "zzzу", "zzzzу",
                                                    "zzzzzу", "zzzzzzzу" };
           cout << *lower_bound(begin(sorted_strings), 
                                end(sorted_strings), "zzzy");
        }
```

I expect the `cout` to print `"zzzу"`, because `lower_bound` should print the element which is equal to or greater that the `val` parameter.

However, things get weird when I run the same line of code in a function outside the `main()`:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
pair<RandomIt, RandomIt> FindStartsWith(RandomIt range_begin, 
                                        RandomIt range_end, const string& prefix) {

    // Empty range
    if (range_begin == range_end)
        return { range_begin, range_begin };

    // When there is at least one word with the prefix
    RandomIt it_begin = lower_bound(range_begin, range_end, "zzzу");
    cout << (*it_begin) << endl;
    return {{}, {}};
}

    int main() {

    const vector<string> sorted_strings = { "zzzу", "zzzzу", 
                                            "zzzzzу", "zzzzzzzу" };
    cout << *lower_bound(begin(sorted_strings), end(sorted_strings), "zzzy") << endl;
    const auto mo_result = FindStartsWith(begin(sorted_strings), 
                           end(sorted_strings), "zzzу"); 
    return 0;
    }
```

**What I expect**: both `main()` and `FindStartsWith()` to print `zzzу`

**What I get**: only `main()` does that.

Comment: _"What I get: only main() does that."_ Continue your problem description! What does `FindStartsWith` do instead?

Comment: I get a segfault when I run your code (after adding includes and namespacing) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c36bfc1e3a529132 Double-check that the result of `lower_bound` is not `range_end` to home in on your logical problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suspect OP is trying to fool us. The problem is in the string literals...

Comment: @liliscent: How so?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You remove all OP's string literal, totally. Then type them by yourself, then everything is fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are some zero with unicode characters in the literals. Funny guy. This cost me -4. Nice.

Comment: @Bathsheba Exactly.

Comment: Edit so I could reverse my upvote. That's 20 minutes of my time I'll never get back. My fault entirely of course. At least I now know std::begin and std::end are the same type for a std::vector.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I remind you to **assume good faith**. There is no evidence that this was deliberate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Let's make it compulsory to submit all code using vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string literal in the function has hidden characters in it, so there is *no* match from `lower_bound`.

And because you never check that the result of `lower_bound` is not `range_end` before dereferencing it, you have undefined behaviour.

The function should use `prefix`, anyway.

Comment: Is the right answer. We got there in the end. Damn OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have some non-printable or wide characters in the string literals in the source code above. Funny guy.

(You then are attempting to dereference an iterator at `end()`, the behaviour of which is undefined.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think the OP is being funny. The non-print suppresses the `cout` message.

Comment: The what suppresses the what now?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Who cares, they are just different! `auto` and `template` to the rescue.

Comment: I don't think there would be different type required till they're iterator to the same object types.

Comment: Also could you modify the function/program so that it behaves as expected by the OP.

Comment: I was incorrect about needing two template types. For `std::vector` the types of std::begin and std::end are the same by the standard.

Comment: Removed the downvote, upvoting for finding the issue.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And to think I upvoted your answer ;-) . Should I get a "super-sportsman" badge for that? Added the UB bit anyway.